# Use toFixed() to elements of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, tofixed

I have an array containing numerical values like this:

```
myArray = [432.2309012, 4.03852, 6546.46756];
```

I want to have maximum 2 digits after the dot so I use toFixed(2):

```
myArray.forEach(a => a.toFixed(2));
```

The result that is returned is `undefined`. Is something wrong?

Comment: you need `map` and to reassign the result to `myArray`

Answer (score 8):

You are not setting the value back. For each just iterates over the array and does not return anything. Use `.map` instead.

```js
myArray = [432.2309012, 4.03852, 6546.46756];
myArray = myArray.map(a => a.toFixed(2));
console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

`forEach` does not return any value and that is the reason why you are getting undefined. Use `map` instead

```js
let myArray = [432.2309012, 4.03852, 6546.46756];
let result = myArray.map(a => a.toFixed(2));

console.log( result );
```

For more info, you can check doc of [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

---

If you really want to use `forEach`, you have to `push` each value to an array

```js
let myArray = [432.2309012, 4.03852, 6546.46756];
let result = [];
 
myArray.forEach(a => result.push( a.toFixed(2) ));

console.log( result );
```